# Trying to hide a group of text with div id in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Ok I'm really dumbing this down to try and see whats going on. I have all this inline in my app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb file so there should not be any problem with rails finding the js.

I have a button...

```
<input type=button value="toggle foo" onclick="showHide('toDate');">
```

the in my div...

```
 <div id="toDate">
    To Date
    <%= text_field_tag "to_date" %>
    </br>
  Days to Exclude
  <% Date::DAYNAMES.each_with_index do |day_name, wday| %>
    <% if day_name == "Sunday" || day_name == "Saturday" %>
      <%= check_box_tag "ignored_days[]", wday, true %>
    <% else %>
      <%= check_box_tag "ignored_days[]", wday %>
    <% end %>
    <%= day_name %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

Then the js...

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(elementId) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
            if (element.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
                element.style.visibility = 'visible';
            } else if (element.style.visibility == 'visible') {
                element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Ideas?

Comment: When are you calling hide? Bound to a click, on document ready, somewhere else?

Comment: Can you share the snippet of code which represents the inclusion of javascript lib and jquery?

Comment: I have //= require jquery //= require jquery_ujs in application.js

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You are also going to want to hide the toDate "on page load". Surround it in a function, like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('#toDate').hide();
})
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I have//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
 in application.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the code after the HTML has been rendered, you can achieve that by doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#toDate').hide();
});
```

Be sure that both jQuery and your asset file are imported in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure jQuery is included, make sure you are running your code inside a jQuery document on ready block like so:

```
$(function(){
  $('#toDate').hide();
});
```

Also note that the new versions of rails include turbolinks, which breaks the document.ready event of jQuery partially. To circumvent this you can intercept the turbolinks events or include jquery.turbolinks as described here: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks

Comment: Nope...did not work. I am able to add an alert("test"); and I can see the alert, so I know JS is working. Also no errors in the console.